# Pandas Dataframe time shift columns

Tags: python, pandas

I got an unevenly distributed dataset, each entry with a `time`, which is a Timestamp object. Now I would like to create a new column by shifting back each column by a certain amount of time (choose the closest entry after shifted time).

An example:

```
      a    b    c                time
0     0    1    2 2018-08-20 15:00:00
1     3    4    5 2018-08-20 15:00:03
2     6    7    8 2018-08-20 15:00:05
3     9   10   11 2018-08-20 15:00:12
4    12   13   14 2018-08-20 15:00:13
5    15   16   17 2018-08-20 15:00:14
6    18   19   20 2018-08-20 15:00:20
7    21   22   23 2018-08-20 15:00:25
8    24   25   26 2018-08-20 15:00:33
9    27   28   29 2018-08-20 15:00:34
10   30   31   32 2018-08-20 15:00:40
```

Expected output (shift backwards by 10 seconds):

```
      a    b    c                time  shifted_a  shifted_b  shifted_c
0     0    1    2 2018-08-20 15:00:00          0          1          2
1     3    4    5 2018-08-20 15:00:03          0          1          2
2     6    7    8 2018-08-20 15:00:05          0          1          2
3     9   10   11 2018-08-20 15:00:12          3          4          5
4    12   13   14 2018-08-20 15:00:13          3          4          5
5    15   16   17 2018-08-20 15:00:14          6          7          8
6    18   19   20 2018-08-20 15:00:20          9         10         11
7    21   22   23 2018-08-20 15:00:25         18         19         20
8    24   25   26 2018-08-20 15:00:33         21         22         23
9    27   28   29 2018-08-20 15:00:34         21         22         23
10   30   31   32 2018-08-20 15:00:40         24         25         26
```

My thought is using `bisect.bisect_left` to record the position of the closest time, then add the shifted numbers one by one. I wonder whether there's a better solution?

Comment: Hi Kevin Fang. You asked a question about linear regression and I came up with a way to do it... but you deleted your question :(.... let me know if you're still interested in the solution and I'll send it to you.

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry Thanks for your effort! I'm sorry because I changed my design. I'll reopen the question and you're more than welcome to answer that question! Just give me 1 minute!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `DatetimeIndex` and then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by shifted `datetime`s with method `bfill` for back filling `NaN`s:

```
df = df.set_index('time')
df = df.reindex(df.index-pd.Timedelta(10, unit='s'), method='bfill')
print (df)
                      a   b   c
time                           
2018-08-20 14:59:50   0   1   2
2018-08-20 14:59:53   0   1   2
2018-08-20 14:59:55   0   1   2
2018-08-20 15:00:02   3   4   5
2018-08-20 15:00:03   3   4   5
2018-08-20 15:00:04   6   7   8
2018-08-20 15:00:10   9  10  11
2018-08-20 15:00:15  18  19  20
2018-08-20 15:00:23  21  22  23
2018-08-20 15:00:24  21  22  23
2018-08-20 15:00:30  24  25  26
```